# Quantitative evaluations for image classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, accuracy, image-processing, computer-vision

Hello I am working on the classification of different weed categories. I want to know what quantitative evaluation I can do other than find the accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of popular evaluation metrics for classification other than accuracy measures such as recall, precision, AUC or F-scores.

Instead of listing them all here, I think it is best to point you towards some interesting resources that can kick-start your search for answers.

This article gives a rather nice overview: 
[Evaluation Metrics for Classification - Medium.com post by Niklas Donges](https://towardsdatascience.com/evaluation-metrics-for-classification-409568938a7d)

A source that is a little harder to follow, but gives a more comprehensive overview of possible metrics can be found in the [scikit-learn model evaluation documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)

Even if you are not planning on using scikit, the metrics remain relevant. It also lists differences between binary classification and multi-class classification setting very thoroughly.

Hope this helps!